# JSF return message to page from bean

Tags: jsf

I have 2 different users, a user and an adminUser.

Login screen example:

```
<h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
                    <rich:notifyMessages stayTime="2000" nonblocking="true"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:inputText id="username" value="#{LoginManager.userName}" title="#{bundle.CreateEmployeesTitle_employeeNo}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.LoginUsernameRequired}" pt:placeholder="Username"/>

                <h:inputText id="password" value="#{LoginManager.password}" title="#{bundle.CreateEmployeesTitle_employeeNo}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.LoginPasswordRequired}" pt:placeholder="Password"/>

                <h:commandLink action="#{LoginManager.loginAction}" value="#{bundle.LoginTabTitle}" styleClass="linkbutton" />
```

my loginManager validates that the username and password match and exist in the database and returns loginPassAdmin when user admin, loginPass when user user and loginFail when username and password does not match or exist. So on my login screen I would like to show a Notification when loginAction returns with loginFail, possibly on the same page if possible?

piece of loginManager:

```
if (userStatus != null) {
            if (userStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("adminUser")) {
                action = "loginPassAdmin";
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("username", userName);
            } else if (userStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("nonAdmin")) {
                action = "loginPass";
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("username", userName);
            } else {
                action = "loginFail";
            }
        } else {
            action = "loginFail";
        }
        return action;
    }
```

Thank you / Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a global faces message. If you use a client ID of `null` in [`FacesContext#addMessage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#addMessage%28java.lang.String,%20javax.faces.application.FacesMessage%29), then it becomes a global message which you can filter using [`<h:messages globalOnly="true">`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/messages.html).

E.g.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(action)); // Substitute "action" with real message.
return null; // <-- Returns to the same view. You can also just declare method void.
```

with

```
<h:messages globalOnly="true" />
```

on a place where you like it.